# Remove node from percona xtradb cluster

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-server

I have a 5 node cluster.  When I run backups it locks the entire cluster. I use DDL statements in a stored procedure that is used heavily.  What I am trying to achieve is taking one node out of the cluster.  Running the backup then adding the node back to the cluster.
How do I remove a node from a cluster?

```
 set wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://192.168.2.59,192.168.2.60,192.168.2.61,192.168.2.62
```

Leaving the the node I want to backup out of the update.
On the node I want to backup do I set wsrep_cluster_address:

```
 set wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://
```

Do I change the cluster name on the node as well?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't remove the node, it's sufficient to desync it from the cluster:

```
SET GLOBAL wsrep_desync=ON;
```

Then do the backup. Then:

```
SET GLOBAL wsrep_desync=OFF;
```

When a node is desynced, it will remain part of the cluster. The node will receive transactions, but not process them. Flow control is disabled, which allows the node to fall behind the cluster. Once we turn off desync again, it will process the queued up transactions.

During desync, the status variable `wsrep_cluster_size` doesn't change, and the node itself will have `wsrep_connected=ON`, `wsrep_ready=ON` as before. However, it will also have `wsrep_local_state_comment='Donor/Desynced'`.

For your DDL statements, I think your options are:

- pt-online-schema-change
- wsrep_OSU_method = RSU
- wsrep_OSU_method = [NBO](https://www.percona.com/blog/percona-xtradb-cluster-non-blocking-operation-for-online-schema-upgrade/)

Comment: When dsync is on does the other nodes see the dsync'd node? Or will they see it but just ignore it.

Comment: @newdeveloper They will see it, but it doesn't process transactions. I've updated my answer to explain a little better.

Comment: I will give this a try.  Changing the wsrep_osu_method wouldn't work.  Stored procedure is heavily used.  I could try setting the wsrep_osu_method per each session when the procedure is executed.  Not sure what kind of headaches would occur.  That was the reason I was hoping to remove the node backup then re add the node.  However this wsrep_desync might work.  Thank you for the help and explanation.

Comment: @newdeveloper Running DDL from a stored procedure sounds a bit unusual, but I have seen stranger things. I forgot to mention, although you may be aware, that some `ALTER TABLE` statements can be done "online" now, i.e. with no or with minimal disruption / locking. (Use `ALTER TABLE .... , ALGORITHM =INPLACE | INSTANT` - inplace since MySQL 5.7 and instant since 8.0. If the particular ALTER TABLE operation you want to do isn't supported by the algorithm specified, then you'll get an error which your stored procedure can catch in a handler).

Comment: The statement DDL command I am using is to create a temp table and insert into the table then select from it then drop a temp table.  I didn't think that was all that weird.